# Use views to prepopulate fields

Tags: entities

I have a site that generates letters to be sent to schools.

The visitor arrives at the front page where they are presented with a map (leaflet map) with all the local schools marked on it. They then can click on a specific school to view its page (node with school location (addressfield) info).

Here they have the option to 'generate a letter to the school' - I have the form (entityform) set up but it needs the visitor to type in the school address again. How can I dynamically fill the address-field in my form  based on the school the visitor navigated to the form from?

map>school>school-specific-form

There are over a hundred schools, so would prefer not to have to duplicate my form...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setting the scene:**

"School-Info" content type = Fields (email, telephone, address, etc...) + Letter generator

- I want to pull the values from the already-populated fields of my "School-Info" content type to my 'letter generator'...
- I did not want the user to have to re-type the school's ([addressfield](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield)) information into the addressfield of my letter-generator because it's hassle and might discourage them from sending the letter.
- Therefore my problem was passing the values of a field-type addressfield to an [Entityform](https://drupal.org/project/entityform) on the same node... and from there to a [pdf](https://drupal.org/project/views_pdf) of that specific entityform submission.
- Generating the PDF from my entityform alone and not on a per-page basis helps me manage the generated letters on a per-user basis ... letter response times can be tracked etc...

I did this:

1. Use [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to make a block that displays the addressfield for the particular school - this can be done by setting a contextual filter for the node ID.
2. Inside the 'letter generator' entity-form type add an entity reference to this view/block.
3. Done

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want coding, this is one possibility:

If you only have one form, but hundreds of nodes, another way I would suggest to do it is to use [Webform Template](https://drupal.org/project/webform_template) for the School content type. You can create one webform template and then reuse it for every school node, but the address field in the webform should have a default value that is a token of the node's address field. All you would need to do is set up your webform template's address field to have a default value of something like [node-field-school-address] and every instance of the webform will have the address of the node it belongs to.

In order to use tokens in a webform, you will need this module: [Webform Patched](https://drupal.org/project/webform_patched) . This is a module that contains the Webform module itself along with token support an therefore the original Webform module should be disabled. I implemented this myself for my site and it worked without any problems.

I never worked with addressfield, but I found this module in case you need it: [Addressfield tokens](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield_tokens)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Webform is not viable at the moment, I am using Entity forms ... The addressfield tokens suggestion was useful. Right now I am currently investigating context-aware views to pre-populate my fields. I'll report back here when I've solved the problem. Thanks.